# Apache Localhost 403 Forbidden with macOS Sierra

Tags: apache, macos-sierra

macOS Sierra update made my Apache's localhost and now is inaccessible. I can only access `localhost/`. But sub-folders under `localhost/<other-directory>/` are not and a "403 forbidden access" error is shown.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39702677/486508

Comment: Reinstall did it for me. Found this complete setup guide as best: https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-sierra/

Comment: the question is not great but google seems to understand (everybody comes here!) so, please reopen it, so I can post another solution (non worked for me). Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Here's the steps I followed to fix this:

Go to /private/etc/apache2
Open httpd.conf.bak, copy the contents, overwrite httpd.conf with it then save

In httpd.conf, change

```
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

to

```
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
```

Change

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
```

Then save

Check the /users/ directory and go to your *.conf file and check it is similar to below:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
# OSX 10.10 / Apache 2.4
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then run sudo apachectl restart

That should then work :-)

Comment: It's still not working, please help me out.. Don't know where I'm stuck

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see local host but I don't see my web files in my directory /Sites. I followed your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem here... followed all the tutorials avaiable, but still no dice. It used to work before the Sierra update.

Comment: [Finally got it worked] Check this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95660/how-to-fix-403-in-mac-os-x-built-in-apache/271178#271178

Comment: Thanks! I put the `<Directory>` command in the top of my `apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and its all sweet now :)

Comment: Like @Rohit for me it was still not working, but it was because /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf was replaced by a new file with just the demo sites, but the old file was left there with the name httpd-vhosts.conf~previous

Answer (score 28):

Please check `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` file.

change

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

to

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

and restart apache.

Comment: Thanks, that line was commented after the Sierra update. What I also found is that after the update, every custom file is renamed with ~previous on the end. There you can find your custom settings

Comment: Thank you!  I love how every OS X update means a new apache2 config!!

Comment: No dice :/ Didn't work for me

Comment: Solution doesn't work.