# Apache giving 404 error after Mac OS sierra update

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-sierra

I just updated to Mac OS 10.11 Sierra lately and classic web server is not working properly, or I should say that my home directory is not working
Apache server is working at localhost as I get the *'It works'* page, but `localhost/~myuser` is giving this message `'The requested URL /~myuser was not found on this server'`
I tried to follow this [tuto](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/) but it is still not working

Can someone help me?

Comment: This worked for me!.
https://tech-cookbook.com/2021/10/25/how-to-setup-mamp-macos-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-12-monterey-2021/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What worked for me after upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra as well:

1) Uncommenting from */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

2) Uncomment from */etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf*

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

3) In my */etc/apache2/users/$USERNAME.conf* file I had *ProxyPass* configured as well, and to get it working again I had to re-uncomment the following from my *httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
```

4) Optional for PHP: You need to re-uncomment the following from the *httpd.conf* as well:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

5) Of course, restart apache

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Things worked for me afterwards, however I am better motivated now to start moving to Vagrant.

Comment: It doesn't for me, but the messages has changed though
I have a 403 forbidden page now
I double checked /etc/apache2/users/username.conf and it contains the following lines which is supposed to be ok
Any other clue?
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>

Comment: I faced the forbidden issue before uncommenting the line mentioned in httpd-userdir.conf, recheck the line that reads *.conf is uncommented. Also to be sure, _chmod 644_ the username.conf file. To try if the username.conf is considered by apache you can put any false expression there and restart, it should show an error.

Comment: @drusixtynine please check the last edit about uncommenting the _Include[...]httpd-userdir.conf_ line at httpd.conf, hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: the line that states Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf is uncommented.
Even if that file has a dummy sample that I didn't change and that gives a warning.
username.conf has a chmod of 644
Yes username.conf is considered, I have an error with a false expression
I am kinda stuck here

Comment: It is working now, I don't know why but I found that in the file extra/httpd-userdir.conf the line 'Userdir Sites' was mistakenly commented. 
Thanks Hesham :)

Answer (score 28):

In Terminal, head to /etc/apache2 and

```
sudo mv httpd.conf httpd.conf.sierra
sudo mv httpd.conf~previous httpd.conf
sudo apachectl restart
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: this worked for me after the above and another SO post. this is the right answer.

Comment: Damn.. now I can't connect to the internet at all on my mac! I know it's some settings thing.. since I can on recovery mode..

Comment: This is the correct answer, except that the ServerName entry still needs to be set

Comment: I did this + renaming the httpd-vhosts.conf file in a similar manner. That sorted it for me. (I absolutely loathe Mac for this, always problems after upgrades.)

Comment: This solution helped me

Comment: I also had to change `php5` to `php7`, i.e.: `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Comment: this showing error 404 for me, can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo mv httpd.conf httpd.conf.sierra
sudo mv httpd.conf~previous httpd.conf

cd /etc/apache2/extra
sudo mv httpd-vhosts.conf httpd-vhosts.conf.sierra
sudo mv httpd-vhosts.conf~previous httpd-vhosts.conf

sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Updating to Mojave deactivated localhosting. A lot of tutorials showed how to re-activate but failed to show phpMyAdmin reworking. This is the ONLY way I've found that brings phpMyAdmin back online. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I also updated my El Capitan to Sierra recently and had similar issue. I checked the /etc/apache2/ and extra directory, what I've notices was all the Apache config files were created at the time of update and they looked default but there were also my custom files from el capitan with ~previous in name. All I had to do was to replace those default for those previous and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

in /etc/apache2/extra

you will see a httpd-vhosts.conf~previous

that is your previous vhosts.conf file.

just use the config file on it.

Works like a charm to me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this and had problems accessing your vhosts after following the chosen answer there was one extra step I had to take.

Inside /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf they had removed the line (in my case it was meant to be right at the bottom of the file):

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/*.vhost
```

And then

```
sudo apachectl restart
```