# 404 when Migrating Go AppEngine app from Ubuntu to macOS

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, macos-sierra, google-app-engine-go

I have an app using go-endpoints to set up a backend. When running locally in Ubuntu I can send requests to the backend and see the API explorer at localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer. I tried moving the code to a new Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and now I get a 404 when trying to send requests to the local server.

I can deploy the app from my Macbook and the backend works as expected so it is just the local server giving issues.

I have tried [this](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api) advice from Google on hitting the API explorer locally.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700357/apache-giving-404-error-after-mac-os-sierra-update) advice on general Sierra issues with localhost servers.

My yaml file is very simple:

```
module: default
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: _go_app
```

I have tried searching every combination of appengine, localhost, go, endpoints, sierra, 404 and none of the solutions work.

Comment: what do you see in the devserver logs?

Comment: Just "default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 19" for curl localhost:8080 or "GET /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 404 19" for trying the API explorer.

Comment: is your local devserver actually listening to localhost:8080? (maybe you have something else listening to that port and devserver is listening to some other port, displayed in the log when the server starts?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is listening, I'm running the same command that I use on Ubuntu and localhost:8080 listens and works when I bring up my frontend app which uses a Python runtime. That's why I think it might be Go related.
devserver output on startup is:

INFO     2017-02-16 19:39:00,646 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56112

INFO     2017-02-16 19:39:00,649 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080

INFO     2017-02-16 19:39:00,654 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

Comment: I'm having this same issue using v1.9.48 of the Go SDK. Assuming it's a new issue, I'm going back through the gcloud SDK versions to try to find where it broke.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the Python SDK (used by the the Go SDK for the development server). Version 1.9.40 works fine, but v1.9.49 is broken. If you're using the GCloud SDK, v137.0.1 is the last working version (includes v1.9.40 of the Python Extensions).